# data-reactroot element height issue

Tags: html, css, react-router

I have a page with a `data-reactroot` inside it. It's height is around 1906px, while the enclosing `divs` and `html` tags are around 915px.

How do I set the enclosing elements to have the same height as the `data-reactroot` element?

I tried this in CSS, but it just simply made all elements have the shorter height, instead of the taller one. I don't think this is the correct solution at all:

```
html, body, #root, #root > div, #root > div > div, #root > div, #root > div > div > footer {
  height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being less of a data-reactroot issue, and more of a general issue where dom elements had a higher height than their parents.

My fix for this is to add `height: auto` to all elements above the larger element, which makes them all the same size.

For example:

```
html, body, div {
  height: auto;
}
```